# Compute integral on a domain

Tags: calculus, integration, plane-geometry

Consider the unit circle $B$ and the unit square $S$ in the euclidean place where we have fix a Cartesian coordinate system.

Let $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = f(-x,-y)$ (even function).

If I know that
$$
\int_S f(x,y) = 1
$$ 
can I deduce straightly (that is without integrate on $S\setminus B$ ) the constant $k$ such that
$$
\int_B f(x,y) = k 
$$ 
?

Comment: $f(|x|,|y|) = f(x,y)$ So $f(-x,-y)=f(|x|,|y|) = f(x,y)$ or $f(x,y)=0$ Are you sure it's odd?

Comment: oups sorry no not odd, I wanted to say even function ... and I edit the property

Comment: I need to know the specific form of $f$. Not sure whether or not there is some relevant theorem helping to solve the problem without knowing the form of $f$. I believe there isn't.

Comment: ok for first examples, I could look in the case where $f$ is a monomial that is
$f(x,y) = x^i y^j$ ($i,j$ odd or even so that $f$ is not in general even but has some symmetry)